# When does Grails constraints work?

Tags: grails, groovy-console

It looks like a basic issue, that I am trying to test Grails constraints in groovy console tool.

Does it work only when I do any database CRUD operations?

Sample code is like this

```
class AAA{
    String a
    String b
    static constraints = {
         a size:5..8
         b nullable:false
    }
}

def x = new AAA(a:'sss',b:null)
println x.a
println x.b
```

Output is

```
sss
null
```

Why are they not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because the `object.validate()`  method is only going to validate these constraints before saving the object.According to the official documentation of grails .

**Constraints provide Grails with a declarative DSL for defining validation rules, schema generation and CRUD generation meta data.** .See below

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

Comment: ok, that mean, i have to implement validate() method. i called x.validate() method but it saying method not defined. I am testing in Groovy Console tool,

Comment: Ok, I understand it won't work in Groovy Console, but in Grails application it works. Grails provides validate method to every domain object. am I right? Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Or please help me how to test constrains in Groovy Console Tool

Comment: @Ravi it will come in grails application only because it is a `GORM` method.I think in groovy you can not test it

Answer (score 0):

there is a wiki about gorm access and validation trought grails console in this [url](https://grails.org/Command+Line+Tools) you may find some help here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one need to stop and run-app again, when using grails console.